# `TargetPLatform.macOS is not yet supported by the maps plugin`, but I'm building it for a web display

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I've got a flutter web app using `google_maps_flutter` and `google_maps_flutter_web` and it works fine on my local machine. When I attempt to build it for deploy to the web server, I get the error `TargetPLatform.macOS is not yet supported by the maps plugin` where a map is supposed to display. The command in `launch.json` for vscode (that works) is:

```
        {
            "name": "my_app",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args":[
                "--dart-define", "BASE_URL=https://~~~~~~",
                "--web-port", "5050",
                "--web-renderer", "html"
            ]
        },
```

The command I use for building the app for deploy is:

```
flutter build web \
        --dart-define=BASE_URL="$base-url" \
        --web-renderer=html
```

I am building the website on a Mac.

Comment: What if you change web-renderer to canvaskit?

Comment: We added `--profile` to the build command and it works everywhere now??!!

Comment: can you add the exact command you ran and how you deployed it? @Jelkimantis

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter build web --profile --web-renderer=html
```

I used this command and it worked!

Comment: but how did you deploy this? its a profile build